# Is there any version of AAVE protocol deployed on polygon/matic testnet?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, testnets, mainnet, aave

As AAVE [documentation](https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/matic-polygon-market) suggests, there is a deployed version of the protocol on matic/polygon mainnet. However, it does not make any mention of those smart contracts on Mumbai testnet which I need to test my DAPP before publishing it on the matic mainnet.
Does anybody know about its availability as well as contract, token and aToken addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is seems that the documentation at https://docs.aave.com/developers/deployed-contracts/matic-polygon-market has been updated and you can find all the information you seek in the « Mumbai » which is the Polygon testnet see https://blog.pods.finance/guide-connecting-mumbai-testnet-to-your-metamask-87978071aca8 for more info on Mumbai

Answer (score 0):

Use http://buildbear.io/ and create your own Testnet by forking Ethereum, Polygon, Binance, Optimism, Arbitrum, Fantom, and Avalanche chains, allowing you to test AAVE protocol on the actual Mainnet state.